# Create min date time in c# with AM

Tags: c#, datetime

Can anyone help. I need to create a datetime object which will return the following when ToString() is called

"1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"

To better frame the question. I'm writing a test for an existing method. It's that method that's calling ToString on a DateTime passed to it. It then compares to the "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM". Right now I'm just trying to characterize the current behavior of the method I don't want to make any changes to it yet. What I'm trying to find out is if it's possible to create a DateTime which when it's ToString is called will produce that string and if so how.

Thanks

Comment: Oh come on.. Have you _ever_ search on Google about how to format your DateTime? There are tons of documentations, articles, topics about that. Please show some research effort.

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DateTime.MinValue.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

If you want all DateTimes to be formatted American when calling `ToString()` You need to set en-US as the active culture.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

All calls to `ToString()` will now be formatted American style. But we aware that **all** other data types such as `float` and `decimal` will also be formatted American style.

Comment: While this is correct and more succinct that my answer, does it return days as `dd` or `d` (I genuinely don't know)?

Comment: As `d` exactly as requested.

Comment: To better frame the question. I'm writing a test for an existing method. It's that method that's calling ToString on a DateTime passed to it. It then compares to the "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM". Right now I'm just trying to characterize the current behavior  of the method I don't want to make any changes to it yet. What I'm trying to find out is if it's possible to create a DateTime which when it's ToString is called will produce that string and if so how.

Comment: *"To better frame the question"* ... you should edit your question then instead of describing you question in a comment on somebody's answer.

Comment: I did that at the same time Jim - you could always scroll up

Comment: @Magnus I didn't downvote by the way, I was simply asking :)

Comment: Thank you @Magnus - the change of CurrentCulture was what I needed here

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the `DateTime` like so

```
DateTime.MinValue.ToString("d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will display the date exactly as you have requested

One way you could set this up is to create a new `static class` which specifically does this

```
public static class MyDateTime
{
    public static string ToS(DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToString("d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

This would be called like so

```
string test = MyDateTime.ToS(DateTime.MinValue);
```

As the class is static, it does not need to be instantiated.